# Prevent UISearchController from displaying searchResultsViewController on first keystroke / character

Tags: ios, search, uisearchcontroller

I'm performing search asynchronously, so I only want the request to be submitted after the user presses 'enter'.

The search interface looks like this:

[image: awesome Icelandic horse]

However, `UISearchController` assumes that results are available on the first keystroke, and presents the `searchResultsViewController` (my own `UITableView` subclass) immediately:

[image: hmmm]

This isn't great, because the user gets distracted by the whole bunch of empty rows and doesn't know why it's being presented.

Setting `hidden` on the view controller doesn't seem to have helped.

I want to present the results pane only once my results come back. How can I hide the results view controller until then?

Answer (score 0):

UISearchControllerDelegate has a [presentSearchController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchControllerDelegate/presentSearchController:) method you can implement to customise the presentation to delay it until results are available. This might work if UISearchController doesn't have some undocumented requirement that the results controller must be presented when presentSearchController returns.

Another approach that I've used is to set up the results table to have a special "in-progress" table cell that gets displayed while you're waiting for results. This cell contains a spinner that shows something is being loaded.